# Comparing vectors of random vectors manually

Tags: vectors

I am sorry if my question is obvious but I really couldn't get an answer.
If $X> Y$ and $Z>W$, does that make the vector $(X, Z) > (Y, W)$, whether $X,Y, Z$ and $W$ are constants or random variables?
Thank you.

Comment: What is the definition of > for vectors?  In general it is undefined.

Comment: I meant normal relational comparison operators, example 2>1. In fact, I am doing a proof for something. I need to show that F(X, Z)> F(Y, W), so I wonder if I can show (X, Z) > (Y, W).

Comment: You need to define the relationship specifically.  For example a partial ordering could be defined as $(X,Z)\gt (Y,W)$ when $X\gt Y$ and $Z\gt W$.

Comment: Thank you Herb Steinberg for your comments. I see your point. The exact example I have is the following: I know : X + A < A  but I want to show that F(X + A, B) < F(A, B). So, can I do this: X + A < A  ==> (X + A, B) < (A, B)?

Comment: You still have not defined ">" for the vector.

Comment: Would it be weird if I say that I don't know how to define ">". I looked at partial ordering and total ordering, so I think it is the partial ordering.

Comment: There is no well-defined ordering for vectors.  In my previous note I defined a possibility.  In that case the answer to your question is "yes" by definition.  Another ordering could be by magnitude.

Comment: So by magnitude, is it sufficient to compare the lengths of the two vectors to say that one vector is > than the other? but I want to make sure that I am asking the right question, are the arguments (2 arguments) of a utility function considered as a vector?

Comment: No.  What I am trying to say is that order among vectors is NOT defined.  You can make up a definition for the purpose of your question, but there is no standard one.

Comment: Thank you @herbsteinberg